# Converting WSDL to PHP source code

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, converters, artifacts

A third party provided a [WSDL specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language), through which I'm going to transfer data to a remote application using [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP).

I'd like to convert all declared types, constants and method signatures to corresponding classy PHP source code.

Today, I gave [WsdlToPhp](https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp) a try. As far as I figured out, this converter doesn't convert any detail. Furthermore, the **documentation has a few rough edges**... Maybe a better converter exists.

**Q: Could someone propose a stable WSDL to PHP converter**?

Please note, that I need a converter to be **run offline** on a development machine. The WSDL specification isn't publicly available. Therefore, I'm **not able to upload** the WSDL to a remote converter service.

Comment: can you be more explicit about "this converter doesn't convert any detail. Furthermore, the documentation has a few rough edges... Maybe a better converter exists." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i done it once, use the pear wsdl lib 
http://pear.php.net/reference/SOAP-0.9.4/SOAP/SOAP_WSDL.html#methodgenerateProxyCode

Answer (score 3):

I used [Wsdl2phpgenerator](http://wsdl2phpgenerator.github.io/wsdl2phpgenerator/) recently. It was pretty easy to use and the generated code has not let me down yet.